# Origin of the expression "and then I found five dollars"

Tags: etymology, expressions

My family often uses the expression "and then I found five dollars" to end a story that even the teller now realizes was rather pointless. The notion is to add a little (undeserved) punch.

A search on the internet shows that that usage is actually quite common, but I don't see any origin listed. Does anyone know where that usage originated and/or where it was popularized?

---

<s>I tried looking via [google ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=found+five+dollars&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfound%20five%20dollars%3B%2Cc0)
The earliest possible use I find is in a [google books search](https://books.google.com/books?id=HhBEAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22found+five+dollars%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=), but I can't quite tell without more context. As a commenter points out this looks to be used in the actual sense but given that the questioner was frustrated I thought perhaps it could be an origin. Now that I see how hard it is to acquire that source, I rather doubt it had enough influence to start the expression anyway.</s>

Comment: Your link is to an irrelevant "natural" usage (where the speaker really *did* find five dollars). I doubt the usage you're talking about (described [here](http://lessonsforoldpeople.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/vocabulary-lesson-and-then-i-found-five.html) as ***a phrase Young Hip People use to end a boring or irrelevant story***) goes back more than a decade or two, but I stand to be corrected on that. I'd hardly say it's been "popularized" though - the meaning should be obvious in context, but I don't recall ever hearing it before now. (Disclaimer: IANAYHP :)

Comment: [This Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=and%20then%20you%20found%20twenty%20dollars%3F) entry implies the *I found five* version (spoken by the boring tale-teller) was preceded by someone in his ***audience*** interrupting with *And then **you** found **twenty** dollars* (as an exclamation, or rhetoricial question, I dunno).

Comment: Yes you are correct that it is used in the actual context there, but as I was trying to find an origin it seemed appropriate. I noticed that the questioner had his "impatience returning". It is possible that it is unrelated yes.

Comment: More context for your 1927 cite: [*Last August, that day I went into town to the Chatauqua they were holding, **I found five dollars.** Gramma. You never told me. Mary. I never told anybody.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22chatauqua+they%22&nfpr=1&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1999&tbm=bks&ei=58nLWZDdG-KKgAa7yImwBQ&start=10&sa=N&biw=1172&bih=830&dpr=1) It's not "possible" that's unrelated to your "idiomatic" usage - it's 100% ***certain***.

Comment: Ah indeed. Thanks. I had just edited the question to deemphasize that, now I think I will strike it entirely.

Comment: People could say any number of "attention-grabbing non-sequiturs" in such contexts. I wouldn't mind betting that [*and then I kicked a hobo*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/tags.php?tag=and%20then%20i%20found%2020%20dollars), for example, "predates" your version (if "dating" such usages is meaningful, which I doubt).

Comment: I hadn't heard that one. Indeed there could be other variants which might be interesting, but the predominance of the $5 (or I guess $20) versions still has me curious.

Comment: I have to say I think the chances of finding anything you could call an "origin" for any of the usages mentioned thus far must be pretty much non-existent. But good luck with it!

Comment: Sounds like a potential punch line to a shaggy dog story: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shaggy-dog%20story